# Search Dialog is not called onSearchRequested()

Tags: android, search-dialog

I have been stuck on this for a little while now. I have looked at other answers on `SO` but they did not help me solve my problem.

My problem is that the search dialog is not invoked by `onSearchRequested()`. I am not able to figure out what is going on with my search...

The relevant code is as below...

**Manifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".SearchableActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

**/res/xml/searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >

</searchable>
```

I have the string resources defined in `strings.xml`.

**SearchableActivity class**

```
public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          Log.d("SEARCH", "HERE");
          handleIntent(getIntent()); 
       } 

       public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 
          setIntent(intent); 
          handleIntent(intent); 
       } 

       public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
          // call the appropriate detail activity
       } 

       private void handleIntent(Intent intent) { 
          if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) { 
             String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY); 
             doSearch(query); 
          } 
       }    

       private void doSearch(String queryStr) { 
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), queryStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } 

}
```

The piece of code in the activity that is invoking the search...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getTitle().equals("Search")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search = "+onSearchRequested(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return onSearchRequested();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`onSearchRequested()` is returning `true`. But the `SearchableActivity` is not called. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

---

**UPDATED**

Never mind! I figured it out!

The solution was to move the `meta-data` outside the `activity` tag and inside the `application` tag. Have added below as an answer for those who run into this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You need to declare FULL path to Search activity

```
<meta-data
          android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
          android:value="com.example.search.SearchableActivity" />
```

Comment: don't know why the official documentation leaves out this important point

Comment: Classic Googlers - happened to me at least 100 times - they just always (!!!) forget to mention something super important in their doc, so one has to search internet for 2 hours just to make something work...Is it really that much to ask for an accurate, up to date and complete documentation?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to move meta-data outside activity tag unless you want every activity in your application to provide the search dialog. The reason it probably didn't work for you is because you put meta-data to wrong activity and moving it outside resolved the problem.

Do not confuse `ResearchActivity` with Activity that calls it like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

It gives no error, but doesn't work. Working example:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

`MainActivity` is the activity that provides search dialog(it can be also [search widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget)) and `SearchableActivity` is activity starting after user requests search and `onSearchRequested()` is invoked.

Comment: Tomek gave the right answer. I have separate activities of main activity and searchable activity. I expect main activity to call searchable activity. I think Android is really confusing to have **android.app.default_searchable** and **android.app.default_searchable** with similar naming but different meaning. It just got new Android programmer confused.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working.

The solution was to move the `meta-data` outside the `activity` tag and inside the `application` tag, as below...

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".SearchableActivity" />

<activity
    android:name=".SearchableActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

Thanks!

Comment: this will work but it is not required to put it outside activity tag. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

you must `override` `onNewIntent()`

change manifest to

```
<activity
    android:name=".SearchableActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"
        android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried adding `android:value=".SearchableActivity` to the `meta-data` but did not help.

Comment: hey try overriding the onNewIntent()